# What is a reasonable setting for Hibernate Search MassIndexer?

Tags: performance, lucene, hibernate-search

In my application I use *Hibernate Search* to manage a *Lucene* index of some of my mapped model classes (10 classes, partly associated to each other -- using `indexEmbedded` quite some time in the index definitions). There are approx. 1,500,000 documents to index

For rebuilding the whole index, I use a mass indexer as proposed in the documentation 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.3/reference/en-US/html/manual-index-changes.html

```
fullTextSession
    .createIndexer()
    .batchSizeToLoadObjects(200)
    .cacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)
    .purgeAllOnStart(true)
    .threadsToLoadObjects(10)
    .threadsForIndexWriter(10)
    .threadsForSubsequentFetching(5)
    .startAndWait();
```

My database connection pool has a size of 50

I observe that the indexing procedure starts promising fast until it reached about 25% of all documents. After that the performance declines drastically (the next 5% take twice as long as the first 25%) and I am wondering why this happens?

- Do I have a wrong ratio of object-loading threads and indexing threads?
- Or is it simply due to the growing size of the index? Does this justify this decline of performance?
- How to improve the performance? How to achieve a constant progress in time?

Because I make use of projections rather than letting Hibernate Search fetch search results from DB, many of my indexed fields are stored in Index (`Store.YES`). Does this affect the performance significantly?

-- Edit:

My Hibernate search configuration:

```
properties.setProperty("hibernate.search.default.directory_provider", "filesystem");
properties.setProperty("hibernate.search.default.indexBase", searchIndexPath);
properties.setProperty("hibernate.search.indexing_strategy", "manual");
properties.setProperty("hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size", "200");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you profiled your application. It is hard to give general recommendations in this case.

Also what configuration settings do you use? There are several properties which can influence the indexing behavior. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindex-massindexer for more details. What's about memory consumption during indexing. Have you monitored this as well.

> Because I make use of projections rather than letting Hibernate Search fetch search results > from DB, many of my indexed fields are stored in Index (Store.YES). Does this affect the 
>   performance significantly?

I would expect that it mainly influences the index size not so much the indexing performance.

Comment: Now I applied jvisualvm to profile. At the moment it is getting slow, CPU load is going down, heap size remains at a high level but does not grow any further. In the fast beginning, CPU load is much higher and the heap size is increasing successively. Most of the indexing threads are waiting, the entity-loading threads are running. There is an increasing number of char[] and HashMap objects.

Comment: If the indexing threads are idle the problem might be the loading of the entities. Do you have some sort of loop between your entities resulting in a big load from the database. Have you seen that there is a _depth_ parameter on _@IndexEmbedded_. Of course it will depend on your model whether this is a problem. It might also help to turn on debug logging for Hibernate Search. It might give you a hint what's going on.

Comment: Yes, I actually have some circular dependencies among my entities and I already used that depth parameter. When removing some indexEmbedded, it indeed runs much faster. Having had a look at the Hibernate SQL log, I find that associated entities are fetched when indexing a parent entity although the childs are indexed once more on their own (there arises another question which is a bit off-topic here) I have to review, which associations are really necessary for my usecases. Thanks Hardy.